# Ошибка Unhandled promise rejection Node.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, rest

столкнулся с проблемой при разработке базы данных с запросами на node.js + PostgreSQL, когда делаю запрос в Postman не взаимодействуя с базой данных, а просто выводя в консоль то все работает, как пытаюсь сделать post запрос к базе данных сразу вылетает эта ошибка

> (node:692) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
> (node:692) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code."*

```
const db = require('../db');
class PostController {
    async createPost(req, res) {
        console.log(req, res);
        const { title, message, image, likesCount } = req.body;
        console.log(title, message, image, likesCount)
        const newPost = await db.query('INSERT INTO posts (title, message, image, likesCount) values($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING * ', [title, message, image, likesCount]);
        res.json(newPost);
    }
    async getPosts(req, res) {

    }
    async getOnePost(req, res) {

    }
    async updatePost(req, res) {

    }
    async deletePost(req, res) {

    }
}

module.exports = new PostController()
```

Answer (score 1):

Это не проблема node + PostgreSQL.

Запустите такой код в node ...

```js
async function foo() {
  throw new Error('error')
}

void async function () {
  const bar = await foo()
  const data = bar.json()
}()
```

... и увидите ту же ошибку.

`foo():Promise` завершился с ошибкой, которую необходимо обработать. В данном примере использовать `try/catch`.
Вам придется порыться в коде и найти этот самый неразрешенный `Promise`.

Да, вот такие они `Promise`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ) разобрался)